# Bind default value to dropdown list from datatable c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

**Code**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    ddlYear.DataSource = GetYear();
    ddlYear.DataBind();
    ddlYear.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--");
    ddlYear.Items.Insert(1, "All");
}

public static DataTable GetYear()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strcon))
        {
            conn.Open();
            string strQuery = "SELECT Previous_Year AS Year FROM Year UNION ALL SELECT Current_Year FROM Year";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

My datatable returns the below value

```
2014
2015
```

Now on page load my dropdown values should be like the below and by default I need to show 2014 value in the dropdown list.

```
--Select--
   All
  2014
  2015
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add your data from your database by using the `DataSource` and `DataBind()` function.

You can add a default option to your select by creating a new ListItem and insert it at the beginning of  your items.

```
ListItem item = new ListItem();
item.Text = "All";
item.Value = "-1";

this.ddlSelectBoxId.Items.Insert(0, item);
```

**To select 2014:**

```
this.ddlSelectBoxId.SelectedValue = "2014";
```

Here `ddlSelectBoxId` is the Id of your ASP Dropdownlist control.

**To display the current year, you can use the following:**

```
this.ddlSelectBoxId.SelectedValue = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
```

**To display the first item from your `DataTable`:**

Make sure you have sorted using the SQL command to your needs, after that use:

```
this.ddlSelectBoxId.SelectedValue = DataTable.Rows[0][0];
```

This takes the first row and the first column of your first row. DataTable is your variable returned by your function.

Comment: I do not want to hardcode the value 2014 and it has to be dynamic. Means it has to pick the minimum value from the datatable.

Comment: Do you want to display the current year? If so see update of my answer!

Comment: The year table which has year information, the value can be like `2014,2015` and later on it can be `2015,2016` and even sometimes it can be `2012,2013`. So among these combinations it has to select the minimum value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
ddlYear.DataSource = GetYear();
ddlYear.DataBind();
ddlYear.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--");
ddlYear.Items.Insert(1, "All");
ddlYear.Items.FindByValue("2014").Selected = true;
```

Comment: I do not want to hardcode the value 2014 and it has to be dynamic. Means it has to pick the minimum value from the datatable.

Comment: @Michael How it could be dynamic? If so you have to do some magic!

Comment: @Michael:While binding you just order the result in ascending order. Even after adding `select` and `all` to the dropdownlist, definitely the third item will be the minimum value.

Comment: @Ullas - But how can I pick that third value and populate in the dropdown. You mean like this `ddlYear.SelectedIndex=2;`

Answer (score 1):

If the sequence is directly 2014,2015..... then you can set the appenddatabounditems property of drop down list to true.

Also,
On page load

```
ddlYear.DataSource = GetYear();
Dim L As New List(Of string)
For Each item As ListItem In ddlYear
L.Add((item.Value).ToString());
Next
ddlYear.selectedvalue = L.Min();
ddlYear.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

I Hope you want to select the current year as selected by default. You can do that by

```
ddlYear.SelectedValue=DateTime.Today.Year.ToString()
```